# Unable to read crash dump in windbg

Tags: windbg, adplus

I have been getting a stackoverflow exception in my program which may be originating from a thirdparty libary, microsoft.sharepoint.client.runtime.dll.

Using `adplus` to create the crash dump, I'm facing the problem that I'm struggling to get any information from it when i open it in windbg. This is what I get as a response:

```
> 0:000> .restart /f

Loading Dump File [C:\symbols\FULLDUMP_FirstChance_epr_Process_Shut_Down_DocumentumMigrator.exe__0234_2011-11-17_15-19-59-426_0d80.dmp]
User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available

Comment: 'FirstChance_epr_Process_Shut_Down'
Symbol search path is: C:\symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 7 Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: Server, suite: Enterprise TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Thu Nov 17 15:19:59.000 2011 (UTC + 2:00)
System Uptime: 2 days 2:44:48.177
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:13:05.000
.........................................WARNING: rsaenh overlaps cryptsp
.................WARNING: rasman overlaps apphelp
......
..WARNING: webio overlaps winhttp
.WARNING: credssp overlaps mswsock
.WARNING: IPHLPAPI overlaps mswsock
.WARNING: winnsi overlaps mswsock
............
wow64cpu!CpupSyscallStub+0x9:
00000000`74e42e09 c3              ret
```

Any ideas as to how i can get more information from the dump, or how to use it to find where my stackoverflow error is occuring?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that the process is 32-bit, but you are running on 64-bit, therefore your dump is a 64-bit dump. To make use of the dump you have to run the following commands:

```
.load wow64exts
.effmach x86
!analyze -v
```

The last command should give you a meaningful stack trace.

Comment: ok sorry for the late response, i found the problem but this should help me none the less... but your idea seems good

Answer (score 1):

This page provides lots of useful information and method to analyze the problem.
http://www.dumpanalysis.org/blog/index.php/2007/09/11/crash-dump-analysis-patterns-part-26/

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if your code is managed or unmanaged. Assuming it is unmanaged. In debugger:

```
.symfix
.reload
~*kb
```

Look through the call stack for all threads and identify thread that caused SO. It is easy to identify the thread with SO, because the call stack will be extra long. Switch to that thread using command `~<N>s`, where  is thread number, dump more of the call stack using command `k 200` to dump up to 200 lines of call stack. At the very bottom of the call stack you should be able to see the code that originated the nested loop.

If your code is managed, use [SOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) extension to dump call stacks.