# Task Scheduler + Intermittantly failing + How do you debug or get a dump + windows7

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have 5 scheduled tasks that are scheduled to run every day at 9.30am. The schedule is basically a vbs script that opens an excel workbook and runs a macro. These 5 schedules can run fine if i run them seperately and 9 times out of 10 they run fine if I simulataneously run them from task scheduler. I do this by highlighting them all and then pressing run.

But sometimes when the task scheduler is doing its schedule they will fail. Sometimes all of them fail, sometimes some of them fail, but most of the time they all succeed.

Once I okay the errors(will post this next time it occurs) I can see the excel.exe in my Processes in TaskManager they are left hanging. I cannot see them in Applications because I run them in the background. Whilst here I know I can right click on the excel.exe and do a Create Dump file, but not sure what to do with this.

**What I am interested here is discovering why they are failing? How do I debug it? Can I get a dump? how do i do this?**   I am sure the code is not perfect but the fact that they run fine seperately and most of the time fine together I am wondering is some memory resource getting used up at this time. This is what I would like to find out.

I know that i could space them out to run every minute, and this is something I might do but I would like to answer my questions above first.

**Note:** The vbs script in question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229716/moving-from-task-scheduler-in-xp-to-windows7) in a previous question I asked.

**EDIT1** Some useful links I have come accross following Noodles answer: 
[WinDBG: The very basics](http://www.sevenforums.com/crash-lockup-debug-how/310617-windbg-very-basics.html) 
[question re: reading dump file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168098/unable-to-read-crash-dump-in-windbg)

**EDIT2**
If i right click on `check for a solution` I can click on `View Technical Details` and that gives me:
[image: This picture]
`
Description
Faulting Application Path:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   EXCEL.EXE
Application Version:    14.0.7128.5000
Application Timestamp:  5398dfdc
Fault Module Name:  EXCEL.EXE
Fault Module Version:   14.0.7128.5000
Fault Module Timestamp: 5398dfdc
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   0023e751
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
Locale ID:  5129
Additional Information 1:   8bde
Additional Information 2:   8bdedbea09a2027adb218b0e009eebf2
Additional Information 3:   d4c1
Additional Information 4:   d4c17b47443511f18e75ae920aa444bd

Extra information about the problem
Bucket ID:  361665432
`

EDIT3 : [A useful walkthough example with commands](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/anandbms/archive/2005/04/20/410225.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Crash Dumps**

Load in Windbg. Then *File* menu - *Open Crash Dump*. Type `!analyze` (note wrong spelling)

**Debugging**

You can also start in a debugger.

windbg or ntsd (ntsd is a console program and maybe installed). Both are also from Debugging Tools For Windows.

Download and install Debugging Tools for Windows

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363

Install the Windows SDK but just choose the debugging tools.

Create a folder called Symbols in C:\

Start Windbg. File menu - Symbol File Path and enter

```
srv*C:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

then

```
windbg -o -g -G c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /k batfile.bat
```

You can press F12 to stop it and kb will show the call stack (g continues the program). If there's errors it will also stop and show them.

Type lm to list loaded modules, x *!* to list the symbols and bp symbolname to set a breakpoint

If programming in VB6 then this environmental variable link=/pdb:none stores the symbols in the dll rather than seperate files. Make sure you compile the program with No Optimisations and tick the box for Create Symbolic Debug Info. Both on the Compile tab in the Project's Properties.

Also CoClassSyms (microsoft.com/msj/0399/hood/hood0399.aspx) can make symbols from type libraries.

You can schedule this command line instead.

**Autostarting Programs in Debugger**

You can also make windbg attach to any specific program when started. See gflags.exe. Only in GUI mode.

**Errors**

Also get the error number. TS keeps a history of runs and their errors. TS has a history tab.

### .

Comment: tks.that sdk is for windows 8. will that work for windows 7, that I have? DOH! Just saw it, it does.

Comment: have added this `srv*C:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`. now where do I do this `windbg -o -g -G c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /k batfile.bat` had tried it in CMD but it is saying `'windbg' is not recognized as an internal or external command` tks

Comment: Look somewhere like "C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\windbg.exe" You put your own command in, not the batchfile in the example. Setup should have added windbg to the path.

Comment: What about analysse of a crash dump and TS's error in the history. You are basically doing this to get an error number and source. If it's already there??

Comment: Again tk u very much but i might be a bit out of my dept.I have added windbg to the path. I have done the following `windbg -o -g -G c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe lm`  and `windbg -o -g -G c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe x !` each opening up `windbg` and a command window with lots of `ModLoads` and another `CMD` window. Can you point me somewhere to read up on this?

Comment: It comes with a very large and technical help file. What you want to do is get an error number. I gave 4 ways and you are choosing the hardest. Is the error number in Task Scheduler on the History tab. Does Control Panel - Problem Reports and Solutions (maybe Action Centre your version) have the crash.

Comment: tks for bearing with me.`Task Manager` is not showing any errors. I went to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Action Center-> view Reliability history` and I can see 2 microsoft excel critical events (for today)that stopped working and there is an action to `check for solution`. I click this and it says `When solutions are available, they will appear in Action Center`. Any other ideas?

Comment: In the details it will give details on the error. What is the number and what is the fault module and/or source.

Comment: can't see any details you are referring to. Am I loooking in the right place?

Comment: In Vista you right click and choose Details in History section. Right click everywhere and look for links. See if there are panes or modes.

Comment: That means Excel is referencing memory it does not have access too. This is an Excel bug. It's probably in a rare codepath. All you can do is wait for MS to release a fix, and they only do fixes that help many people. However always with office try a Help menu - Detect and Repair. This may move the codepath from mis handling a configuration error back to normal codepath.

Comment: WinDbg can get more info on it, but it's unlikely to help.

Comment: Tks very much, I will follow all that up.